# How/can I plug a 3 wire 4-20mA current sink probe into a 2 wire 4-20mA loop powered controller?

Tags: 4-20ma

I have a 3 wire 4-20mA output probe [simulated here](http://lushprojects.com/circuitjs/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+4.818269829109882+62+5+43%0AR+480+0+480+-32+0+0+40+20+0+0+0.5%0Aw+304+144+320+144+2%0Aa+320+160+400+160+9+9+0+1000000+0.4899865192169092+0.49+100000%0Aw+320+176+320+208+0%0Ar+400+160+448+160+0+5600%0At+448+160+480+160+0+1+-17.86761983613968+0.6316953789067103+100%0A370+480+0+480+48+1+0%0Ar+480+208+480+256+0+120%0Aw+320+208+480+208+2%0Aw+480+176+480+208+0%0Ag+480+256+480+272+0%0Ar+480+48+480+96+0+250%0Aw+480+96+480+144+0%0Ap+528+48+528+144+1+0%0Aw+480+48+528+48+0%0Aw+528+144+480+144+0%0A172+304+144+256+144+0+7+0.49+2.5+0.49+0+0.5+Voltage%0A), where during normal operation the 20v and 250 ohm resistor are variable chosen by the user.

One of my users has a 2 wire 4-20mA meter, and I am unsure what the normal approach to 2 wire 4-20 is.

Can i plug my probe into the user's controller? If so what wires go where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. (a) 2-wire and (b) 3-wire. Source: copied from my answer to [Several Questions About Analog Input](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/421399/several-questions-about-analog-input/421420#421420).*

> ... but if I can have non isolated power provided externally can I tie my 3 wire signal line to the + terminal on the 2 wire controller and tie ground to the - terminal?

Yes. Consider Figure 1b. The 24 V supply is feeding the 3-wire transmitter while the grounds are connected. The 24 V could be supplied from the receiver panel or could be supplied locally at the transmitter.

As an aside, the 250 Ω resistor shown in the receiver is the typical way to convert the mA signal to a 1 to 5 V signal for the internal ADC.

---

[image]

*Figure 2. OP's schematic.*

You have placed the 250 Ω current sensing resistor in the high side of your device. That means they can't share a common ground.

> One of my users has a 2-wire 4 - 20 mA meter, and I am unsure what the normal approach to 2-wire 4 - 20 is.
>   Can i plug my probe into the user's controller? If so what wires go where?

You can **provided** the user's meter is not grounded. If it is you will have a short across the transistor and lower resistor - always give designations to components on schematics - resulting in 20 V DC applied across the 250 Ω resistor which will pass 80 mA.

Your configuration is unusual and this could give rise to problems on installation.

Comment: Is the transmitter in your figure (b) a current source? i edited my post to have my output circuit and want to make sure its the same type.

Comment: I thought I understood what you were asking but with the addition of the simulation link I now have no idea. Can you edit your question to make it clearer?

Comment: i rewrote the question

Comment: Be careful with rewriting when folk have answered already as it makes their posts look irrelevant. Please see the update.

Comment: Thanks, i will just redo the design to be a current source similar to figure 1

Comment: @Transistor  A link to where you got the graphic may help the OP. In many industrial configurations there may be multiple receivers associated with a sender. The diagrams you show DO NOT handle this situation. It is very common for a 4-20mA sensor/sender to be connected to a computer input Rx and an indicator (which works when the computer is off/failed).

Comment: @Jack: Figure 1 is mine and from my answer to [Several questions about analog input](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/421399/several-questions-about-analog-input/421420#421420). Feel free to cover the multiple receivers in your own answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Transistor. The link to the question makes sense ….you should put that link in your answer. If I have time today I'll post and answer.

Comment: @JackCreasey: Done.

Answer (score 1):

[This TI chip](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/xtr117.pdf) is how a 2 wire input to 2 wire 4~20mA current loop is used so that ground noise does not degrade the result , yet is not galvanically isolated.

A 5V regulator inside the XTR117 is like the LM117/317 and needs a Vcc = 7.5 to 24V to drive the IC.

The chip is basically a current amplifier and the series input R converts the input voltage to a small input current then the chip amplifies this current with an output offset of 4mA and a gain of **Io=100 x In** to 20mA full scale.  The input may also be offset with a bias resistor to +5Vreg or some other source.  THere is also examples of how to protect it from reverse and over-voltage and RF interference.

> This means you can choose Rin to have just about any scale of Vin {min,max} to equate to {4:20}mA output. e.g. Vin = 0:1V,  or 0 to 3.3V or 0 to 5V or 2.8V to 4.2V ...etc.

[image]

This IC can work in most applications unless there is a real need for high voltage or galvanic CMRR optical isolation.  But don't reinvent the wheel, THis IC is 0.3% accurate over temp and supply range.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I plug a 3 wire 4-20mA current sink probe into a 2 wire 4-20mA loop powered controller?

Short answer: Yes

Longer answer, the configuration will change depending on both the sender and receiver.

A three wire sender includes a + line, 0V line and sender output (source from + or sink to 0V).

You should read [this](https://instrumentationtools.com/4-20-ma-transmitter-wiring/).

If your Rx is loop powered then the connection would typically look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHhQwe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first diagram shows a 4-20mA Sink, the second a 4-20mA source.